# How to improve the response time for an old IPAD app

Tags: ios, performance, sqlite

I have an IPAD app developed about 10 years back.  All are working well except the response time.  The UI started getting slower as we moved from IOS 9 to 10 and later when IOS 11 came in, still slower.  Is re-writing the whole code is the best option?  Or are there certain areas I can focus on?

Along these years, I migrated our code to latest XCode. Current builds are on XCode 10.  Users are running latest IPADs too.

Few questions related to the performance:

- Current devices, builds, libraries are 64 bit.  Possible that my earlier implementation was using some 32 bit component which may be slowing our app. There are no network component involved.  Just a local database and UI. I tried with only arm64 build on IOS11 iPAD with no noticeable improvement
- I have sqlite database used in the app.  The original database was created 10 years back.  Do I need to migrate the database file to new sqlite?  (I mean start from a brand new sqlite file?)
- I migrated from sqlite to sqlite3 library (link library) some time back.  I did not make any changes in the class or methods.  Will it cause any slow response?
- I am still using the old xib files (not the ones created from storyboard).  Will it cause slowness?

Any other point that I can focus on to try out?

Comment: Probably the first thing to do is run the time profiler instrument.  Also ensure you have enabled the main thread checker to alert you to any UI updates that aren't being performed on the main thread